# Clarification on indexing numpy array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am a high school student and looking through some numpy code, I found something along the lines of

```
a = x[:,0:4]
```

and x was a 2-d array. I know that a[:], refers to all objects in array a, so for x[:,0:4], would it refer to all rows of x and columns with index 0,1,2,3 excluding column with index 4?

Just trying to get confirmation about how this works because I have seen it in several types of code and just wanted to be sure.

Comment: You got it.  The docs are pretty decent - [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html) and [http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. This `a = x[:,0:4]` selects the first four columns.

Example:

```
>>> a = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])
```

You can skip the `0` because  `a[:,:4]` means the same as `a[:,0:4]`:

```
>>> a[:,:4]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [10, 11, 12, 13],
       [15, 16, 17, 18],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

You can always think: "First dimension first, second dimension second, and so on." In the 2D case the first dimension is the rows and the second dimension is the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is referred to as slice notation and numpy arrays can also use Python's slice notation, so

```
>>>x = np.arange(25).reshape(5, 5)
>>>a = x[:, 0:4]
>>>a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
   [10, 11, 12, 13],
   [15, 16, 17, 18],
   [20, 21, 22, 23]])
```

If you use the slice notation, `x` will be a view of `a` and not a copy, so if you change a value in array `x`, the value will also be changed in `a`.

```
>>>x[1,1] = 1000
>>>a
array([[   0,    1,    2,    3],
       [   5, 1000,    7,    8],
       [  10,   11,   12,   13],
       [  15,   16,   17,   18],
       [  20,   21,   22,   23]])
```